# CloudKit slow response time?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cloudkit

I'm trying to switch from Parse to CloudKit and got my sample working so far. 
I got a CLoudKitModel which looks like this:

```
class CloudKitModel {
    let container: CKContainer
    let privateDB: CKDatabase
    let publicDB: CKDatabase

    init() {
        container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
        publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    }

    func getPlayers(completionHandler: (data: [CloudKitPlayers]?, success: Bool) -> ()) {
        var playerArray = [CloudKitPlayers]()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortID", ascending: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Player", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
            let players = CloudKitPlayers()
            players.age = record["age"] as! Int
            players.name = record["name"] as! String
            players.nickname = record["nickname"] as! String
            players.position = record["position"] as! String

            let imageData = record["image"] as! CKAsset
            players.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageData.fileURL.path!)

            playerArray.append(players)
        }

        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("Fetched all players")
                if playerArray.count > 0 {
                    completionHandler(data: playerArray, success: true)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(data: nil, success: false)
                }
            }
        }

        self.publicDB.addOperation(operation)
    }
}
```

and I call this `getPlayers(completionHandler: )` function in an `UITableViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let cloudKit = CloudKitModel()
    cloudKit.getPlayers { (data, success) in
        if success {
            if let playerArray = data {
                self.players = playerArray
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
                print("reloaded tableView")
            }
        } else {
            print("no success")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: It takes on average about 10 seconds to display the names in the TableView. It's not that I'm getting like a thousand records at once, these are just 8 data-sets that I'm loading from iCloud.
I read that I should perform the `tableView.reloadData()` on the main thread, but that didn't help either.

Is there something else that I'm missing or a particular way how to debug this? Compared the Parse this solution is like 10x slower...

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: What does the output from `Time Profiler` show? Which part of your code is slow? Or is the problem the network? Before you can debug the problem you need to understand the problem by measuring it.

Comment: The 'Time Profiler' did say anything special. My network should not be the problem either (connected to the WiFi at Home). Do you see anything weird in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting the QOS?

```
operation.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated
```

Comment: Feels like the same, but I will keep this one in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the most speed, you most likely you'll want to load the ***CKAsset* images asynchronously**, so wrap the player image loads in a background thread operation block.

Here is and example from my code that fetches photo's that you can extrapolate from:

```
var backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()

func fetchPhoto(completion:(photo: UIImage!) -> ()) {

  backgroundQueue.addOperationWithBlock() {
    let image = self.record["Photo"] as? CKAsset
    if let ckAsset = image {
      let url = ckAsset.fileURL
      if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:url) {
        self.photo = UIImage(data: imageData)
      }
    }

    completion(photo: self.photo)
  }
 }
```

Then for the table load in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can load the image via the completion block, but you MUST put all UI on the main thread or you will experience random crashes, as in:

```
object.fetchPhoto {
  image in
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    cell.photo.image = image
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem.

4 records took 12 seconds to load.

**Problem**

Performance issues come from `CKAsset`

**Solution**

My solution is remove `CKAsset`(avatar/image). Store avatar/image in [icloud storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW1) (Usage is a little complicated).

Comment: Key-value storage is not a great solution for this. From the document you linked: key-value storage is `Limited to a total of 1 MB per app, with a per-key limit of 1 MB.`